# Can you create dynamic button styles/shapes in Photoshop that resize with text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I need to make rounded buttons (pill shaped) in different sizes that will automatically adjust height/width based on the size/length of text on them.

In Illustrator you can select a text object and create a graphic style that dynamically does this. This is great for mocking up because I don't have to constantly draw buttons and manually adjust their length to the length of the text. I only have to apply a style.

How we create buttons in Illustrator:
[image: Illustrator image]

Photoshop doesn't have graphic styles or any layer styles that replicate this. Are there any filters or plug-ins that can?

The goal is to allow other designers to create the same buttons
regardless of whether they use Illustrator or Photoshop and without having
to jump back and forth with smart objects.

Comment: Basically, no. Photoshop isn't made for dynamics. :)

Comment: Photoshop Design Space https://adobe-photoshop.github.io/ may try to implement something like this, but probably not, since it'd be so drastically different from how Photoshop has always managed shapes, text frames and styles. Especially now that Adobe is working on 'Project Comet'. Future Photoshop feature development will probably focus back on it's roots. http://landing.adobe.com/en/na/products/creative-cloud/comet/229818-notifyme.html

Answer (score 1):

How about making the buttons in Illustrator and import them as Smart Objects in PS, you should be able to scale the Smart Objects?